# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_1^n+\dots+a_k^n)^{1\over n}$ where $a_1 \ge \cdots\ge a_k \ge 0$

Tags: limits

Need to find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_1^n+\dots+a_k^n)^{1\over n}$ Where $a_1\ge\dots\ge a_k\ge 0$

I thought about Cauchy Theorem on limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}=\lim a_n$ and something like what happen if all $a_i=0$ or $a_1=\dots=a_k$, but may be something I am thinking wrong?

Maybe it is too simple but I am not getting it; please help.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/807759/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/722252/321264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that 
$$a_1=[a_1^n]^{1/n}\leq [a_1^n+\cdots+a_k^n]^{1/n}\leq [ka_1^n]^{1/n}=k^{1/n}a_1$$
and apply squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The $n$-th term of our sequence is between $a_1$ and $k^{1/n}a_1$.